# Use constant as filter parameter in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, filter, constants

I' ve a code like this

```
{{ aDate | bxDate : 'WhitoutTimePart' }}
```

I want to change the string 'WhitoutTimePart' as a constant so that, if one day the value change, i don't have to go in every html file to do the modification.

Something like that :

```
{{ aDate | bxDate : bxdate.whitoutTimePart }}
```

Using an enum or a constant would be the best ...

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a constants.js file in your project where you define this and other similar constants like this.

```
 (function(){
          
   app.constant('filterParam', 'WhitoutTimePart');
   
 }).call(this);
```

Then you can import the constant in your controllers and asign it to a scope variable

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

angular.module('myModule')
    .controller('MyController', ['$scope','filterParam', MyController]);


function MyController($scope, filterParam) {

    $scope.filterParam = filterParam;        

})();
```

Then finally in your html

```
{{ aDate | bxDate : filterParam }}
```

Hope this was helpful to you